# React Jest - Mock a function with callback

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I'm trying to write a test for following code

```
var throttle = require('lodash.throttle');

 search = throttle(async (searchTerm:string) => {
    const response = await AxiosWrapper.Instance.post(this.props.url, { "searchTerm": searchTerm });

    this.setState({
        searchResult: response.data as ISearchResult,
        showSearchResult: true
    });
},500);
```

So, my mock looks like

```
 jest.mock("lodash.throttle", () => {
            console.log("blah");
        });
```

I would like to execute callback from throttle func.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [jest docs for jest.mock](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestmockmodulename-factory-options), the second argument is a factory (function) that returns the mock value for the module. In this case, we are mocking the lodash.throttle function, so we want a factory that returns a function. If you want to mock lodash.throttle such that it just calls the callback that is passed in, you would do

```
jest.mock("lodash.throttle", () => cb => cb())
```